# show little message on hover over an image button on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hover, imagebutton

I'm developing a system which uses a lot of image buttons for redirections...
However, I want the buttons to show a little mesage whenever you put the cursor over the button...

Example, when you hover the cursor over the button which redirects you to Schedule, a little message that says "Schedule" appears. That way, the user may not recognize the picture, but when he hovers over the button, he will know where will he be redirected...

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ToolTip` property associated with your image (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip